# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a little problem with a reqular expression in my application. I have following code which works well for all patterns, that are not just '/':

```
if (preg_match("#". $pattern1 . "(/.*+)?#", $pattern2)) {
    $topActive = TRUE;
}
```

When I have `$pattern1` with /line-up or /line-up/opening and `$pattern2` with /line-up/opening it works as expected. But it also matches when I have just '/' as `$pattern1`. what can I do to prevent matching against '/', but let it still match against the other mentioned patterns?

Comment: (/.*+), The * means any number of chars (including 0), + means more than or equal to 1 char, you seem to be mixing them up here?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have corrected it ;) But it does not affect the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. I have to check the found matches against the pattern again.

```
if (preg_match("#". $menuRoute->getPattern() . "(/.+)?#", $route->getPattern(), $matches)) {
    if (isset($matches[0]) && $matches[0] == $route->getPattern()) {
    $topActive = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to match the exact string? E.g.

```
| $pattern1  | $pattern2             |
| /line-up   | /line-up/ or /line-up |
```

Then you can use `^` and `$`:

```
#^$pattern1/?#
```

But if you want to match `/line-up`, `/line-up/`, `/line-up/foobar`, ect. it won't work. You cannot do it.

I think you want this for routing? I think the best option is to put the shortest route (`/`) in front and the longest in the end (`/line-up`).

Comment: I have setup routing and that works very well, but now I want to get some control in my menu structure. For this I want to check if the current pattern (e.g. /line-up/opening) matches the pattern of the menu entry. But the menu entry could not only be /line-up/opening, but also just / and also /line-up/finishing. For /line-up/finishing it works (it does not match) but my problem is the '/'.